# Can't put content behind SWT Wizard Help Button

Tags: button, swt, wizard, jface

I created a SWT based Wizard which has an own help Button by custom. Now i want to put some content behind that, so maybe a SWT browser will be openend and a predifined HTML Doc will be shown. But I don't have any clue where to access the Actions of the Help Button within my Wizard. Any idea?

Comment: Post the code of your wizard, it's quite hard to help you without any piece of additional information..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am **assuming** that you are using the standard JFace interfaces and classes for the wizard implementation. So, in your wizard page (`extending org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`) you just have to override the `performHelp` method. See the below snippet.

```
@Override
public void performHelp() 
{
    Shell shell = new Shell(getShell());
    shell.setText("My Custom Help !!");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322489/cant-put-content-behind-swt-wizard-help-button");
    browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.open();
}
```

**`>>Wizard image`**

[image]

**`>>After pressing the help button`**

[image]