# SWT Help button in TrayDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt, jface

I have a class that extends TrayDialog and that has a help button. I have set the folowing:

```
setDialogHelpAvailable(true);
setHelpAvailable(true);
```

And I can't find how I'm supposed to implement the Help button in the lower left corner. I've tried

```
@Override
protected void buttonPressed(int buttonId) {
    super.buttonPressed(buttonId);
    if(buttonId == IDialogConstants.HELP_ID) {
        System.out.println("Help requested");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've seen [Can't put content behind SWT Wizard Help Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322489/cant-put-content-behind-swt-wizard-help-button) but I have no performHelp() method because I'm not in a wizard.

What am I missing here? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the help button is pressed `TrayDialog` looks for a control with a `SWT.Help` listener. It starts at the currently focused control and moves up through the control's parents until it finds a control with the listener (or runs out of controls).

You can set up a help listener that is connected to a 'help context' in the Eclipse help system using

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(control, "context-id");
```

or you can write your own help listener.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by just adding a `HelpListener` to one of my controls:

```
Composite area.addHelpListener(new HelpListener() { 

    @Override public void helpRequested(HelpEvent e) { 
        System.out.println("This is the help info"); 
    }
});
```

and adding the following to my Constructor:

```
setDialogHelpAvailable(true);
```